# Spring WebClient to Download an Image

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have been looking into Reactive Programming and recently tried to build a POC with Spring WebFlux. I want to start simple and just use the WebClient to download an image; specifically https://greatatmosphere.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/great-atmosphere-149-tenaya-lake-yosemite-national-park-2.jpg

I have tried the following code

```
    String block = WebClient.create("https://greatatmosphere.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/great-atmosphere-149-tenaya-lake-yosemite-national-park-2.jpg")
            .get()
            .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .doOnError(WebClientResponseException.class,
                    ex -> System.out.println(ex.getStatusCode() + ": " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString()))
            .log()
            .block();
    System.out.println("output:" + block);
```

but it does not work as expected. It seems that the data is continually be streamed and the get request does not terminate.

I am certain that I am missing something simple but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have tried a variety of parameters but the results are the same.

How do I use the WebClient to download the image and then terminate?

Comment: is it a reactive application or not? in a reactive application you dont use block.

Answer (score 6):

Catch image as `byte[]` not `String`

```
byte[] image = WebClient.create("https://greatatmosphere.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/great-atmosphere-149-tenaya-lake-yosemite-national-park-2.jpg")
        .get()
        .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
        .block();
```

Comment: Also to note, only byte(primitive) works. I tried to use Byte(class) and got error.